# Basic join and aggregate?

Tags: sql, count, aggregate, inner-join

I have table A, table B and table C.

I want to select 2 fields from table A, one field from table B (an inner join between these two I'm assuming) and the Count for each record where the identifier on table B is found on table C.

So I'll have:

```
OpeartiveId | OperativeNumber | JobLocation | CountOfJobIdInWorkTable
```

Edit:

```
Operative
OperativeId
OperativeNumber

Jobs
JobId
JobLocation

Work
JobId
OperativeId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you also want records from a and b that have no matching records in c, you'll need an outer join:

```
select a.pk_a, b.pk_b, count(c.pk_c) 
from a 
inner join b on a.pk_a = b.pk_a 
left outer join c on b.pk_b = c.pk_b 
group by a.pk_a, b.pk_b;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank, this is actually the case. Did you mean this to read count(c.pk_c)?

Comment: It's not strictly needed (since in my test schema, only the c table contains a column pk_c), but I've added it for clarity - thanks.

Comment: So could this have been count(*)? Or is the count() part of your script a way of saying perform a count on table c, so somehow needed to identify the count with table c? And you did this by using a column unique to c am I right? Thanks again Frank, appreciate it.

Comment: this will return 1 when there are 0 records in table c

Comment: That's strange, I can't run it against my schema at the moment but I wouldn't have expected that.

Comment: @bebonham, it should return 0 if there are no records in c,  I tested in on my database to be sure. Of course I am using SQL server, what db are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Translate this to your actual schema and try it:

```
select a.one, a.two, b.three, count(c.id)
from a
join b on a.id=b.id
left join c on c.bid=b.id
group by a.one, a.two, b.three, b.id
```

Comment: this is what I answered first but what will happen if c doesn't have any bid records

Comment: You need an outer join with c (see my answer).

Comment: Changed to left join to fix that, hopefully

Comment: why do you have b.id in teh group by?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you looking for. looking at the filed you provided i came up with this.

```
select o.operativeId, o.OperativeNumber, j.JobLocation, COUNT(w.jobId)
from dbo.Operative o
Inner join works w
    ON o.OperativeID = w.OperativeId
INNER JOIN jobs j
ON w.jobId = j.jobId
GROUP by o.operativeId, o.OperativeNumber, j.JobLocation
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select a.a,a.b,b.a,(select count(*) from c where c.b_id = b.id)
from a 
join b on a.b_id = b.id
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries are a sql antipattern. They are much slower than using a left join.